# How do you write a dynamic sized 2-D array to parquet file in C++ using apache-arrow?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a 2-D array of variable size:

```cpp
// Initialize 2-D array of x and y values
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, 0.0));
std::vector<std::vector<double>> y(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, 0.0));
}
```

How do I write these values to a parquet file with the following format?

|  | x<sub>0</sub> | y<sub>0</sub> | ... | x<sub>n</sub> | y<sub>n</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `x[0][0]` | `y[0][0]` | ... | `x[n][0]` | `y[n][0]` |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| N | `x[0][N]` | `y[0][N]` | ... | `x[n][N]` | `y[n][N]` |

where n = rows - 1 and N = cols - 1.

Here is my attempt so far:

```cpp
// Create schema for output file
arrow::FieldVector fields;
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    fields.push_back(arrow::field("x_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float64()));
    fields.push_back(arrow::field("y_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float64()));
}
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Schema> schema = arrow::schema(fields);

// Store data into arrow::Table for output
arrow::ArrayVector array_vector;
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arrow::FloatBuilder fbuilder;
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> data_array;
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        fbuilder.Append(x[i][j]);
    }
    fbuilder.Finish(&data_array);
    array_vector.push_back(data_array);
}
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(schema, array_vector);

// Write table to output file
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open("test.parquet", &outfile));
PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::WriteTable(*table, arrow::default_memory_pool(), outfile, 3));
```

The resulting "test.parquet" contains nothing and throws the following error when trying to read it using python:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '<Buffer>': Parquet file size is 0 bytes
```

Comment: 2D dynamic array (or in fact almost *any* dynamic array) in C++ should be spelled `std::vector`. Not this manual memory management nonsense. `double** x = new double*[rows];` - no, just no.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to close `outfile`?

Comment: @Pace adding `outfile->Close();` did not change anything.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I changed it `std::vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a number of errors and compiler warnings trying to run your code.  Make sure you are paying attention to those.  Also, `PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK` should be throwing an exception with what you have.

1. It seems you are mixing up rows and columns.  The following loop is defining your columns.  So why is it `i < rows`?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        fields.push_back(arrow::field("x_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float64()));
        fields.push_back(arrow::field("y_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float64()));
    }
```

2. You are ignoring some potential bad status returns in the array builder methods `Append` and `Finish`.
3. You are defining `2*rows` columns (one set of `x_` and one of `y_`) but you are only creating `rows` arrays.
4. When building your schema you use `float64`.  However, the builder type you are using is `FloatBuilder` which is `float32`.  Use `DoubleBuilder` if you want `float64`.
5. You are passing `&outfile` as the second parameter of `arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open` but `Open` returns a result and does not take in an out parameter.  Instead that pointer is being implicitly cast to a `bool`.

Here is a roughly similar version that does create a parquet file successfully:

```
#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/array/builder_primitive.h>
#include <arrow/result.h>
#include <arrow/status.h>
#include <arrow/table.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/writer.h>

#include <iostream>

using arrow::Status;

namespace
{

  static constexpr int kRows = 100;
  static constexpr int kCols = 100;

  Status RunMain()
  {
    // Create schema for output file
    arrow::FieldVector fields;
    for (int i = 0; i < kRows; i++)
    {
      fields.push_back(arrow::field("x_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float32()));
      // fields.push_back(arrow::field("y_" + std::to_string(i), arrow::float64()));
    }
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Schema> schema = arrow::schema(fields);

    // Store data into arrow::Table for output
    arrow::ArrayVector array_vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < kRows; i++)
    {
      arrow::FloatBuilder fbuilder;
      std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> data_array;
      for (int j = 0; j < kCols; j++)
      {
        ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(fbuilder.Append(i * kRows + j));
      }
      ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(fbuilder.Finish(&data_array));
      array_vector.push_back(data_array);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(schema, array_vector);

    // Write table to output file
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(outfile, arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open("test.parquet"));
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::WriteTable(*table, arrow::default_memory_pool(), outfile, 3));
    return outfile->Close();
  }

} // namespace

int main()
{
  Status st = RunMain();
  if (!st.ok())
  {
    std::cerr << st << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```